# cocos2dx jsb runs jsc file, it always reports Cocos2d: JS: :0:malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 1 (0)

Tags: cocos2d-x

I put all javascript files in a file.
It works well in .js
but if I convert it to .jsc file and run
t always reports

```
Cocos2d: JS: :0:malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 1
```

I searched and found out

```
MSG_DEF(JSMSG_MALFORMED_UTF8_CHAR,    205, 1, JSEXN_TYPEERR, "malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset {0}")
```

is there anyone met the same problem?

**updated question**

first 3,4 lines to the jsc file

```
U¿sπJ.¥πç‹Q/Users/myname/cd-standard/Javascript_projects/Cocos2dxjs/testa/testa/Resources/hello222nounicode.jsW ÅÅÅÄÅÅÅÅÅ¥ÅŸÅÄÅ‰ÅÅÅÅöõúùûü†°¢Å)±Å2Å:ÅiÅoÅpÅsÅtÅÅàÅân;DQY\oQ;?6;<6;XÄ6;>6;<6;◊6;>6;◊6;◊6 ;?6
;?6;>6;◊6
;?6;?6n;DQY\oQ;>6;?6;◊6;◊6;◊6;◊6;◊6;◊6;◊6;◊ 6;◊
6;◊6;>6;?6;>6;?6 ;◊6!;◊6";◊6#;◊6$;◊6%;◊6&;◊6';◊ 6';;56(;>6);?6*;◊6+;>6,;?6-;◊6.;>6/;>60;>61;?62;>63;?64;◊65;◊ˇ66;>67;?68;◊ˇ69;◊ˇ6:;>6;;?6<;<6=;ÿ@6>;ÿ 6?;>6@;?6A;>6B;?6C;YXˇ]E>]F>]G\6D;Y>]EXˇ]F>]G\6H;Y>]E>]FXˇ]G\6I;Y>]E>]F>]G\6J;YXˇ]EXˇ]FXˇ]G\6K;YXˇ]EXˇ]F>]G\6L;Y>]N>]O\6M;<6P;>6Q;?6R;◊Ä6S;◊6T;ZY>]N>]O\`Y>]N>]O\`Y>]N>]O\`Y>]N>]O\`\6U;>6V;Y>]X>]Y\6W;Y>]N>]O>]X>]Y\6Z;YXˇ]EXˇ]FXˇ]G\6[;YXˇ]EXˇ]FXˇ]GXˇ]]\6\;;5_DQ;5^DQ;^6^;Ç6`;Ç6a;Ç6b;Ç6c;;5b6d;;5c6e;Ç6f;Ç6g;Ç6h;Ç6i;Ç6j;Ç    6k;Ç
6l;Ç6m;Ç6n;Ç
6o;Ç6p;Ç6q;Ç6r;Ç6s;Ç6t;Ç6u;Ç6v;Ç6w;Ç6x;Ç6y;Ç6z;Ç6{;Ç6|;Ç6};Ç6~;Ç6nÄ;ÄDQ;ÅoÄQ;Ç6Ç;5ÉÇ6Ñ;5ÖÇ 6Ñ;5Ü;5Ü5á6Ñ;Ç!6à;Ç"6â;Ç#6ä;Ç$6ã;5ãÇ%6å;5ç;5ã5å6å;5é;5ã5å6å;5è;5ã5å6å;5ê;5ã5å6å;5ë;5ã5å6å;5í;5ã5å6å;5ì;5ã5å6å;5î;5ã5å6å;;5ã∏å
‰YÇ&]ñ\‰:6ï;5ïÇ'6ón;DQY\oQ;◊ˇ6ò;>6ô;?6ö;◊6õ;>6ú;?6ù;>6û;?6ü;◊6†;◊6°;◊6¢;>6£;?6§;◊6•;◊6¶;◊6ß;◊6®;◊6©;>6™;?6´;◊6¨;◊6≠;◊6Æ;5ØÇ(6Ñ;5Ø5∞Ç)6±;5≤5∞Ç*6≥;5¥;5ã5å6å;5µ;5ã5å6å;5∂;5ã5å6å;5∑;5ã5å6ån;DQY\oQ;?6;<6;XÄ6;>6;<6;◊6;>6;◊6;◊6    ;?6
;?6;>6;◊6
;?6;?6n;DQY\oQ;;5g6∏;;5h6π;;∏∏
```

related js file lines

```
//
// Javascript Bindigns helper file
//

// DO NOT ALTER THE ORDER
//require('jsb_cocos2d_constants.js');

    /*
    * AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT IT
    * Generated by "generate_jsb.py -c chipmunk_jsb.ini" on 2013-03-05
    * Script version: v0.6
    */

var cp = cp || {};
cp.ALLOW_PRIVATE_ACCESS = 0x1;
cp.ALL_LAYERS   = 0xffffffff;
cp.BUFFER_BYTES = 0x8000;
cp.CIRCLE_SHAPE = 0x0;
cp.HASH_COEF    = 0xc75f71e1;
cp.MAX_CONTACTS_PER_ARBITER = 0x4;
cp.NO_GROUP = 0x0;
cp.NUM_SHAPES   = 0x3;
cp.POLY_SHAPE   = 0x2;
cp.SEGMENT_SHAPE    = 0x1;
cp.USE_CGPOINTS = 0x1;
cp.USE_DOUBLES  = 0x0;
cp.VERSION_MAJOR    = 0x6;
cp.VERSION_MINOR    = 0x1;
cp.VERSION_RELEASE  = 0x1;
```

Comment: post the first line of your jsc file, perhaps try saving it as utf-16 or plain ascii

Comment: I updated and listed the first 3,4 lines of the jsc file

Comment: that looks broken, if JSC is supposed to be a text format (as indicated by the error) then that file is likely corrupt. Otherwise it may be a unicode text format, which may not be supported by Javascript, or it may require UTF-8 encoding. I'm not a JS expert but I think it's safe to say it's a file format issue.

Comment: I change nothing while the original javascript works and use cocos2dx 2.2.1 2.2.2 .30 alpha beta to compile js file to jsc, same error

Comment: maybe compiled javascript is simply not supported?

Comment: Hey arachide , I am also stuck into the same issue. I made a release build using Visual Studio for Windows platfrom (.exe format). But All js file are visible into that so I compiled all js to jsc file, but its not running now. Any solution yet ??